# JavaScript IE rotation transform maths

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, math, rotation, transform

I am working on setting the rotation of an element with JavaScript, I know this is easy to achieve if you want to set to a 90 degree angle but this is not what I want. Because I want to set to strange angles such as 20 degrees I need to use the transform filter. I know the layout of this but I was wondering how I calculate the four values, at first I tried this.

```
calSin = Math.sin(parseInt(css[c]));
calCos = Math.cos(parseInt(css[c]));
element.style.filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=' + calCos + ', M12=-' + calSin + ',M21=' + calSin + ', M22=' + calCos + ', sizingMethod="auto expand")';
```

But as you can see, this was never going to work, I was just taking a stab in the dark. Due to maths not being my strong point I was wondering if anyone could help me calculate the values?

Thanks.

**EDIT**

Okay! Got it working with the following code.

```
radians = parseInt(css[c]) * Math.PI * 2 / 360;
calSin = Math.sin(radians);
calCos = Math.cos(radians);
element.style.filter = 'progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=' + calCos + ', M12=-' + calSin + ',M21=' + calSin + ', M22=' + calCos + ', sizingMethod="auto expand")';
```

But now the question is how do I make it rotate from the center rather than top left?

Comment: See edit for the *new question*. I have managed to rotate it but it needs to rotate from the center, not top left.

Comment: Okay, I have deduced that it is working perfectly other than it does not hang over the edges unlike the other browsers. In chrome it rotates so the corners stick outside the page a bit, in IE the element moves to keep its corners inside. Anyone know how I can stop this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For rotate from the center, you'll need to add `Dx` and `Dy` to IE filter, then add displacement via **css** and add css hacks to increase elements' width and height in IE.

You may look how it's combined on my site: http://kirilloid.ru/

Actually this is more CSS-related question, than javascript.

Comment: So what does Dx and Dy do? And I can't wrap it in a div or anything, this needs to be done via pure JavaScript. I assume Dx and Dy are the offset positions for the rotation? Because I think that is correct already, so I just need to set styles to push it up and left slightly, any idea how? Margin, padding?

Comment: Dx and Dy actaully moves element after rotation. You can use either position:relative + left/top or negative left/top + positive right/bottom margins to move it before rotation. And move + rotation + move back results in rotation around some point.

Answer (score 4):

There actually is a way to do what you're trying to do using just the ie matrix transformation filter.

in addition to M11, M12, M21, M22, the matrix also has two additional properties: Dx and Dy for translation.  Unfortunately, you can't just translate by a constant amount.  In order to rotate about the center of the object, you need to compose three transformation.

First, translate the center of the object to the origin.  Second, rotate the object.  Third, translate from the origin back to where the center belongs.

IE does not have the ability to compose multiple matrices itself, so you have to do the linear algebra yourself.  Suppose theta is the angle by which you want to rotate, and suppose that the object's width is 2w while its height is 2h.  (So w and h are the HALF width and height respectively.)  Let c and s stand for cos(theta) and sin(theta) respectively.

The matrix product you want to compute is then:

```
    [[1 0 w] [[c -s 0] [[1 0 -w]
     [0 1 h]  [s  c 0]  [0 1 -h]
     [0 0 1]] [0  0 1]] [0 0  1]]
```

which equals:

```
    [[ c           -s           (-wc + hs + w)]
     [ s            c           (-ws - hc + h)]
     [ 0            0                   1     ]]
```

So, if you compute the two quantities (-wc + hs + w) and (-ws -hc + h) and add them to your filter as Dx and Dy respectively, the end result will be that the rotation is about the center of the object.

I have coded this up and tested it for a project in which I needed to animate having an object rotate about its center, and this worked for me.

Comment: The most amazing answer on the internet. Thank you mikepr. I know this post is an year old, but, could you please tell me how you got the initial matrix product that needs to be computed?

Comment: Thanks, Kzest. I derived the matrix product from what I recall of my linear algebra courses. The 3x3 (instead of 2x2) matrix transform allows for translation. In this system, a single point is represented as a vertical matrix [x y 1], and you transform it using a 3x3 matrix by standard matrix multiplication with the matrix on the left and the vector on the right. When composing multiple transformations, the transformations are applied from right to left. Here, the right-most matrix translates the center of the image to the origin; the middle rotates it; and the right most translates it back.

Answer (score 0):

You should check https://github.com/heygrady/transform/wiki/correcting-transform-origin-and-translate-in-ie for a comprehensive 50%,50% transform origin IE hack. Be careful, there are a few typos in the last function, here is the correct block:

```
var matrices = {
    tl: matrix.x($M([0, 0, 1])),
    bl: matrix.x($M([0, y, 1])),
    tr: matrix.x($M([x, 0, 1])),
    br: matrix.x($M([x, y, 1]))
};
```

You will also need the Sylvester library: http://sylvester.jcoglan.com/

HTH