# Javascript IE Transform Matrix Calculations

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, internet-explorer, rotation

I am looking to calculate the proper values to rotate a div in IE 6-8. I grabbed the following calculation from this post [JavaScript IE rotation transform maths](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5051451/javascript-ie-rotation-transform-maths), but it doesn't seem to work in IE6 or 7. It works in IE8 so this makes me wonder if it is an issue with the syntax.

```
var angle = 45;
radians = parseInt(angle) * Math.PI * 2 / 360;
calSin = Math.sin(radians);
calCos = Math.cos(radians);

var rotateCSS = 'filter: progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(M11=' + calCos + ', M12=-' + calSin + ',M21=' + calSin + ', M22=' + calCos + ', sizingMethod="auto expand"); '; /* IE6,IE7 */

rotateCSS += '-ms-filter: "progid:DXImageTransform.Microsoft.Matrix(SizingMethod="auto expand", M11=' + calCos + ', M12=-' + calSin + ', M21=' + calSin + ', M22=' + calCos + ')"; '; /* IE8 */
```

$('.rotate').attr('style', rotateCSS);

Comment: http://www.boogdesign.com/examples/transforms/matrix-calculator.html There's also a link to the article.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The element that is being rotated needs to have position:absolute in order to work properly.